# Sci Fi book about Jewish people in space

Tags: story-identification, military-sf

Main character was an inspector general but really an assassin sent to kill his family member who betrayed their people. Also it's about the Jews are mercenaries.

Comment: D.Myers If you are the user that posted the previous question you can follow [the instructions here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This  is [*Not For Glory*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7831) by Joel Rosenberg.

The Inspector General is Tetsuo Hanavi, who narrates the story. His rank of Inspector General in the Metzadan Mercenary Corps is really just a cover that allows him to travel more freely; his real job is assassin for the Metzadan government.

Tetsuo is sent to find (and kill) his uncle, ex-general Shimon Bar-El, who was cashiered in disgrace for apparently betraying Metzada.

Metzada is a world settled mostly by Jewish refugees. (Along with some Japanese, hence Tetsuo's name.)

[image: Not For Glory North American mass market cover]

Comment: "Metzada is a world settled mostly by Jewish refugees. Along with some Japanese, hence Tetsuo's name." Not that this seems to have stopped the illustrator from (I assume) portraying all three cover art characters as blond Ubermenschen.

Comment: @Adamant Probably hired the same people who did the casting for the *Starship Troopers* movie...

Comment: @Adamant Fair comment, especially since the Metzadan aren't drawn so much from the Jewish diaspora as they are specifically the survivors of the nuking of Israel.  (I believe they even refer to Metzada as something like "Beta Yisroel.")

Comment: @David - More likely B'nai Yisrael, children of Israel. If the writer actually knew enough to call the character Beta Israel (and with a name like Joel Rosenberg, they may well have been Jewish, so they may have), that would imply that he was from the Ethiopian diaspora, many of whom immigrated to Israel, adding another later of inanity to the cover illustrations.

Answer (score -1):

I saw the back of a novel called Diaspora- seems the middle east gets nuked (not sure by who or why) and a space station is built to hold a large Jewish population- but I don't know if the main character was an inspector or if he killed anybody.

Comment: This one; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora_(novel)?

Comment: Forgot I asked this before.

Comment: @Valorum- I don't think so, judging from where the link went.